# jQuery callback on img src replacement?

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

What I am trying to do is to change an image on my webpage when the user mouses over a thumbnail of it. It is easy for me to do it this was because the thumbnail src only has 'tn_' appended to the filename and is otherwise identical.

The problem I'm having is that when I switch the src on the image the attr function returns the img dom element almost instantly while the image itself does not change until the new image loads. I want to have some sort of a callback, so that I can either change the cursor to show a loading symbol, or write loading somewhere on the page while the new image is loading.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give the image a [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) callback.

```
$('#imageID').load(function() { .... });
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that load() doesn't always fire when the image is in the browser cache.  You need to add some logic using the DOM img.complete.  Read the comments on load() documentation page for some insight.

Comment: @MPD i know this is old, but this was linked to. If you bind the events to the image prior to changing the src, the events will trigger regardless of cache.